# Matching ggplot legend color with actual color in dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have a data frame that has color column. Sample data is shown below:

```
structure(list(group = c("green", "red", "blue", "green", "red", 
"blue", "green", "red", "blue", "green", "red", "blue", "green", 
"red", "blue", "green", "red", "blue", "green", "red", "blue", 
"green", "red", "blue"), y = c(4.6, 8.3, 4.6, 4.7, 9, 2.6, 9, 
10, 7.5, 6.7, 8.3, 6.2, 6.2, 7.8, 7, 7.7, 9.1, 4.7, 7.5, 7.5, 
8.3, 7.4, 7.6, 5.7), CO = c(3.5, 4.2, 5.9, 3.3, 2.2, 5, 4.4, 
5.5, 5.1, 3.9, 2.1, 4.3, 4.3, 4.5, 5.4, 3.6, 5.8, 4.7, 4.8, 2.9, 
4.8, 4.3, 5.5, 3.4), age = c(18, 19, 25, 18, 22, 18, 29, 19, 
41, 19, 18, 24, 19, 26, 32, 23, 18, 24, 22, 21, 18, 22, 19, 18
), gender = c("Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Female")), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to use "color" column to group observation and plot it in on graph. I wrote the command shown below:

```
ggplot(df_long, aes(x=CO, y=y, color=group, shape=group)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=FALSE)+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+theme(
    legend.title = element_text( size = 14),
    legend.text = element_text( size = 10)
  )
```

The result is shown below:
[image]

As can be seen, the legend doesn't match with the actual color and for example, the group with color "red" is shown with "blue" color. I tired and added

```
scale_color_manual(breaks = c("red", "blue", "green"),
                 values=c("red", "blue", "green"))
```

And this resulted in the following graph:
[image]

First of all the colors are not really appealing and they changed to a different color (somehow really shinny! which makes it hard to see the graph) comparing to the previous graph. More importantly, I have 2 legends now and I am not sure how to fix this. Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you please share a sample of `df_long` using `dput()`?

Comment: Try `scale_colour_identity()`. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_identity.html

Comment: @Duck, my data is really long, but I added a sample of it, to the question

Comment: @Roozbeh_you Nice, I have added a possible solution for your issue, with an example and the data you shared. Let me know if that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach using `scale_shape_discrete()`. Example and code with your data included:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(df_long, aes(x=CO, y=y, color=group, shape=group)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=FALSE)+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+theme(
    legend.title = element_text( size = 14),
    legend.text = element_text( size = 10)
  )+
  scale_color_identity(guide = 'legend')
```

Output:

[image]

Updated to match the colors in variable. Many thanks and credits to **@erc**.

For other colors try this:

```
#Code2
ggplot(df_long, aes(x=CO, y=y, color=group, shape=group)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=FALSE)+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+theme(
    legend.title = element_text( size = 14),
    legend.text = element_text( size = 10)
  )+
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c("red", "blue", "green"),
                     values=c("tomato", "cyan3", "darkgreen"))+
  scale_shape_discrete(breaks = c("red", "blue", "green"))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, That absolutely answers my question. Just out of curiosity, is there any way to change the color back to the colors I had in my frist try? This phosphoric color is not really good, and I am not sure why it changed to this color

Comment: @Roozbeh_you Added a new approach, let me now if that fits your new expected output.

Comment: Thanks so much Duck.

Comment: oh sorry Duck, the second graph you provided, is not correct. It's again showing "red" group" with "blue" color. so basically you changed the color and it's perfect but it still has the main issue

Comment: In the second plot, the colours are as off as in the question? Anyway, as mentioned above, using `scale_colour_identity` is the key.

Comment: Not necessary, this question has been asked million times before. Just need to find one.

Comment: @Roozbeh_you Updated to match what you expected.

Comment: @erc Credited and updated. Many thanks!

Comment: @Duck Many thanks. I guess even the first solution Duck provided was correct. However, the issue with Neon color is still there. Not sure why the color is changing, but that's fine. I will deal with color myself. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Roozbeh_you I have added a new update teaching you how to change the colors. Hope that helps!!!